# robolectric, no intent matches for `receiveResult`

Tags: unit-testing, android-intent, robolectric

See my code:

```
doSomeActionWillStartNewIntentToSelectImage();

// check started intent
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
Assert.assertThat(activity, new StartedMatcher(intent));

// simulate the returning result
shadowOf(activity).receiveResult(
        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI),
        Activity.RESULT_OK,
        new Intent().setData(activity.drawableId2Uri(R.drawable.icon_ok)));
```

But it reports an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No intent matches 
    Intent{action=android.intent.action.PICK, data=content://media/internal/images/media} among 
   [Intent{action=android.intent.action.PICK, data=content://media/internal/images/media}]
at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.receiveResult(ShadowActivity.java:381)
```

It's strange that `Intent{action=android.intent.action.PICK, data=content://media/internal/images/media}` is exactly the same as the later one.

Where is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The intent passed into `receiveResult` is not the same one started by the activity.

The correct test code should be:

```
doSomeActionWillStartNewIntentToSelectImage();

// check started intent
Intent intent = shadowOf(activity).getNextStartedActivity();
assertThat(intent.getAction()).isEqualTo(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
assertThat(intent.getData()).isEqualTo(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

// simulate the returning result
shadowOf(activity).receiveResult(
        intent,
        Activity.RESULT_OK,
        new Intent().setData(activity.drawableId2Uri(R.drawable.icon_ok)));
```